# pandas series extractall error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series (named df) in the following format:

```
                     col1
  a               GEOS 13100
  b               MATH 13100-MATH 13200
  c               MATH 19100-19200
  d               SPAN 10300 or 20300
  e               EGPT 10101-10102-10103
  f               MOGK 10100/30100
  g               PHSC 12600 must be taken before PHSC 12620
```

I want to extract all courses ("[A-Z]{4}\s*\d{5}" or "\d{5}") from col1. The desired data set will be in the following format:

```
          col1        col2          col3          col4        col5
a      GEOS 13100
b      MATH 13100      -          MATH 13200
c      MATH 19100      -          19200
d      SPAN 10300      or         20300
e      EGPT 10101      -          10102            -          10103
f      MOGK 10100      /          30100
g      PHSC 12600                 PHSC 12620
```

I tried

```
df.col1.str.extract('(([A-Z]{4}\s*\d{5}?)|(\d{5}?)).*?(and|\-|or|\, or|\:|\/|\.|\;|\(|\s?)')
```

and got the first matched pattern.

I tried

```
df.col1.str.extractall('(([A-Z]{4}\s*\d{5}?)|(\d{5}?)).*?(and|\-|or|\, or|\:|\/|\.|\;|\(|\s?)')
```

but got the following error:

```
Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.
```

Anyone has any idea what I should do?

Comment: can you post your desired data set?

Comment: I just posted it. Thank you! @MaxU

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of pandas, you might have run into something like [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/13156) (although your indices appear to not be of the problematic form). In version 0.19.0, both cases run without errors:

```
In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['SPAN 10300 or 20300', 'SPAN 10300 or 20301', 'MOGK 10100/30100', 'PHSC 12600 must be taken before PHSC 12620']})

In [26]: df.index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
                                     col1
a                         SPAN 10300 or 20300
b                         SPAN 10300 or 20301
c                            MOGK 10100/30100
d  PHSC 12600 must be taken before PHSC 12620

In [28]: df.col1.str.extract('(([A-Z]{4}\s*\d{5}?)|(\d{5}?)).*?(and|\-|or|\, or|\:|\/|\.|\;|\(|\s?)')
/usr/local/bin/ipython:1: FutureWarning: currently extract(expand=None) means expand=False (return Index/Series/DataFrame) but in a future version of pandas this will be changed to expand=True (return DataFrame)
  #!/usr/local/bin/python3.5
Out[28]: 
        0           1    2  3
a  SPAN 10300  SPAN 10300  NaN   
b  SPAN 10300  SPAN 10300  NaN   
c  MOGK 10100  MOGK 10100  NaN  /
d  PHSC 12600  PHSC 12600  NaN   

In [29]: df.col1.str.extractall('(([A-Z]{4}\s*\d{5}?)|(\d{5}?)).*?(and|\-|or|\, or|\:|\/|\.|\;|\(|\s?)')
Out[29]: 
              0           1      2    3
  match                                    
a 0      SPAN 10300  SPAN 10300    NaN     
  1           20300         NaN  20300  NaN
b 0      SPAN 10300  SPAN 10300    NaN     
  1           20301         NaN  20301  NaN
c 0      MOGK 10100  MOGK 10100    NaN    /
  1           30100         NaN  30100  NaN
d 0      PHSC 12600  PHSC 12600    NaN     
  1      PHSC 12620  PHSC 12620    NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [172]: df.col1.str.extractall(r'(\w{4}\s\d{4,}|\d{4,}|[\-/]|or)').unstack().fillna('')
Out[172]:
                0
match           0   1           2  3      4
a      GEOS 13100
b      MATH 13100   -  MATH 13200
c      MATH 19100   -       19200
d      SPAN 10300  or       20300
e      EGPT 10101   -       10102  -  10103
f      MOGK 10100   /       30100
g      PHSC 12600  or  PHSC 12620
```